# For any random variables $X,Y, Z$, does the identity $Var(X|Y,Z) \leq Var(X|Y)$ hold

Tags: probability

In the paper BYOL [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07733), on Page $5$ the authors state that
for any random variables $X,Y,Z$ that $Var(X|Y,Z) \leq Var(X|Y)$.

Writing out both sides of this inequality, assuming that the random variables are discrete (I'm assuming the continuous case is similar),

$$LHS = Var(X|Y=y,Z=z) = \sum_{x \in X} ( x - \mu_{x'})^2 \frac{P(x \cap y \cap z)}{P(y \cap z)}$$ where $$\mu_{x'} = \mathbb{E}_{(x,y,z) \sim P(x|y=y,z=z)} [X|Y=y,Z=z]$$ (not sure if this notation is correct), and

$$RHS = Var(X|Y=y) = \sum_{x \in X}( x - \mu_{x''})^2 \frac{P(x \cap y)}{P(y)}$$ where $x'' = \mathbb{E}_{(x,y) \sim P(x|y=y)} [X|Y=y]$.

It seems to me that $P(x \cap y \cap z) \leq P(x \cap y)$, but in the expressions for variance, the denominators differ.

Any hints or insights why this inequality is true (or if this is an error) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should study first the simpler case $\operatorname{Var}(X|Z) \le \operatorname{Var}(X)$

But this is false. The conditional variance is a function of $Z$, and for some values it will be below the unconditioned variance, for some values above (in general).

Think for example of $X,Z$ taking values on $\{(0,0),(0,1), (1,0) \}$ with probabilities $1/3$ each. Then $\operatorname{Var}(X|Z=1) < \operatorname{Var}(X)$ but $\operatorname{Var}(X|Z=0) > \operatorname{Var}(X)$.

The inequality is true "in average", i.e.

$$E[\operatorname{Var}(X|Z)] \le \operatorname{Var}(X)$$

More concretely ([law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)).

$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[\operatorname{Var}(X|Z)] + \operatorname{Var}(E[X|Z]) $$

This all is also true if we condition everything on $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I understand now. To understand the law of total variance, I first had to learn about the "law of iterated expectations", and then watched this short proof video about the law of total variance here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHonq7Gjjqg .

Comment: And if I understand correctly, by conditioning on a single event $Y$ uniform on the single event set ${1}$, then in your example $Var(X|Z=1, Y=1) < Var(X|Y=1)$ but $Var(X|Z=0, Y=1) > Var(X|Y=1)$.

Comment: @leonbloy can we assume that $X' = X|Y$ and substitute $X'$ for $X$ in your formulas?

Comment: @quester Basically, yes. But don't ask me to prove it :-)

Comment: @leonbloy looking on your SE reputation it will not hurt if I will take your word for it :)

Answer (score 1):

For the inequality you propose, we would need to show

$$E[(E[X \mid Y] - X)^2 \mid Y] \geq E[(E[X \mid Y, Z] - X)^2 \mid Y, Z]$$

which is equivalent to:

$$E[X^2 \mid Y] - E[X \mid Y]^2 \geq E[X^2 \mid Y, Z] - E[X \mid Y, Z]^2$$

However, this is false. Consider taking $X$ uniform on the set $\{-2, -1, 1, 2 \}$, set $Y$ independent of $X$, and set $Z = X^2$. Then, the inequality above collapses to $E[X^2] \geq X^2$, which is not true when $X = \pm 2$.

The inequality you propose would be true if one were to take expectations though (by the minimizing property of conditional expectations)

Comment: Can you elaborate why the inequality $$E[X^2 \mid Y] - E[X \mid Y]^2 \geq E[X^2 \mid Y, Z] - E[X \mid Y, Z]^2$$ collapses to $E[X^2] \geq X^2$, I'm having a bit of difficulty seeing why that's true.

Comment: If X and Y are independent, E[X^2 | Y] = E[X^2]. Similarly, if X^2 is a function of Y and Z, then E[X^2 | Y, Z] = X^2.

Comment: For the second one, I am using the shorthand that people regularly use; namely, X \leq 5 means that for every \omega, X(\omega) \leq 5